# LIKE Statement not Working Properly in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I have this piece of code to return search results from my database:

```
$search_stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from `books` WHERE `title` LIKE '%testing1234%' ORDER BY `rating` DESC, `title` ASC LIMIT 1000");
```

This is a piece of my database:

```
---------------------
| id |title         |
---------------------
| 1  |testing1234   |
---------------------
| 2  |Testament...  |
---------------------
```

That doesn't return anything from my table.

Replacing `testing1234` with `testing`, this returns row `1`.

I've also tried replacing `testing1234` with `test`, this returns both rows.

I've also replaced `LIKE '%testing1234%'` with `REGEXP 'testing1234'`, but I get the same results with `REGEXP` as I got with all of my `LIKE` statements.

When I put my original query into Sequel Pro, it returns row `1`.

So my conclusion is that I'm not using PDO properly, any help to get me going in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you use `'%testing123%'`?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any issues here. See Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fefc3/1

Comment: See [**PDO  info**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) on how to use LIKE

Comment: @JayBlanchard `'%testing123%'`, `'%testing12%'` and `'%testing1%'` all return nothing.

Comment: Can you try: '\%testing123\%'? It could be possible that % starts a variable name for the prepared query.

Comment: @moo I tried that and it won't return anything at all.

Comment: @Trinimon's example works perfectly fine, so I'd suggest finding out what you're actually doing. Connect to MySQL using the command line `mysql` utility, and then run your query on your database. If it works there, it should work in PDO and your code's doing something odd. If it *doesn't* work there, then there's odd things going on with your table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to make sure the the `charset` is defined whne establishing a connection to the database.

This is the original code for connecting:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . '', $db_user, $db_pass);
```

This is the way it should be done:

```
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
```